# Github Actions' Job keeps running in all branches

Tags: github-actions

I thought I limited only to main when I ran the following yml config on Github actions but it runs on other branches

```
name: Deploy to Amazon ECS

on:
  push:
    branches: 
      - main
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  install:
    name: NPM install
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: '12.13.1'
    - name: NPM install
      run: |
        cd app/
        npm install
    .....
        
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs:
      - install
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'
    steps:
    - name: Checkout 2x
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
```

When I push to a branch like one of the features it still runs the install job, I dont have a problem because I added the if statement on deploy, and it should run tests on each branch but I don't understand why it runs on any other branch.

[image]

As you can see the Install Job is running in another branch

[image]

Comment: This PR from `feature/mercadoPagePse` wasn't open against the `main` branch?

Comment: I think this happens when the pr is accepted

Comment: The way you informed it, the workflow will trigger every time a PR is opened against the main branch or when you PUSH a new commit to the main branch. There are other options to customize PR and PUSH triggers on the Github documentation: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows